# Explanation of Stone-Weierstrass theorem's proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-explanation, weierstrass-approximation

> **Theorem:**
>   Let $A \subset C(K)$ such that
>
> 1. $A$ is a subalgebra with unity $1$
> 2. For each $x, y \in K $ with $x \neq  y $, there exists $f \in A$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$.
>
> Then $ \overline A = C(K)$, where $C(K)$ is the space of continuous functions over the compact space $K$.

*Proof:*
We have to show that for every function $f\in C(K)$, for every $x\in K$ and for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $g_x \in \overline A$ such that $g_x\le f+\epsilon$ and $g(x)>f(x)$.

Then we define $\ h_{xy}$ by $h_{xy}$=p$g_{xy}$(z)+q, where constants p and q are such that $\ h_{xy}$(x)=f(x)+$\epsilon$/2 and $\ h_{xy}$(y)=f(y)-$\epsilon$/2.

Then by 1), $h_{xy}$ $\in$ A.

My question is: why can we say $h_{xy}$ $\in$ A by 1) ?

Comment: It's not clear what is $g_{xy}$, but, I assume it's supposed to be in $\bar A$, then $p\cdot g_{xy} + q\in \bar A$.

Comment: @Berci I think the same it's not clear but in the proof (of a pdf file) it was like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof explanation of Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251668/proof-explanation-of-stone-weierstrass-theorem)

Comment: @Bowditch my question is different in both questions

Comment: Could you post a link to the PDF you're referring to?

Comment: If $A$ contains 1 it contains all constant functions and this allows us to use the $p,q$ constant functions to correct the values as claimed, staying in $A$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'd like to post the link of the pdf but I don't remember the wed page :( sorry. Fortunately I downloaded it but I don't know how to send to you

Comment: Is it the PDF in the linked possible duplicate? The notation is very similar

Comment: @HennoBrandsma oh god i'm so silly..yeah of course it's the same file. Sorry again

Comment: Condition 1. is not stated precisely. It could be interpreted to mean that $A$ has a multiplicative identity, rather than that the constant $f$ that maps $K$ to $1$ is a member of $A.$ The former interpretation is insufficient. The latter interpretation is what  should have been "spelled out."

Comment: @DanielWainfleet you're right I haven't notice it.Now following the pdf of [this question] [1]  can you explain me why if a continuous function is in a set U then U is open? Thanks in advance. [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2251668/4280

Comment: Where is the $U$ mentioned in your link? BTW your link is a proof for a compact metric space $K.$  The Stone-W. theorem applies to any compact Hausdorff $K.$  Most contemporary authors do not assume that compact means compact Haudorff.  I don't think the theorem is valid without the "Hausdorff".

Comment: In the first part of the second photo @DanielWainfleet

Comment: The sets in the cover are open , because if $f,g$ are continuous from $X$ to the reals $f-g$ is also continuous, and $\{x: f(x) < g(x) + \varepsilon\} = (f-g)^{-1}[(-\infty , \varepsilon)]$ ,the inverse image of an open set under a continuous function; this is a completely standard and often used fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the PDF in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2251668/4280), we get $g_{xy} \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\alpha:=g_{xy}(x) \neq  \beta :=g_{xy}(y)$, as the algebra separates points (as this property is called). Then $1 \in \mathcal{A}$, and $\mathcal{A}$ being an algebra (so closed under scalar multiplication with the field $\mathbb{R}$), gives us that all constant functions are in $\mathcal{A}$ as well, and as $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under addition and pointwise multiplication, it contains all functions of the form $pg_{xy} + q$. Now the simple observation is that there is a linear function (from reals to reals) that maps the two distinct points $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to the points $f(x) - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $f(x) + {\varepsilon \over 2}$. This linear function $z \mapsto pz + q$ (easily computable) gives us the constant functions $p$ and $q$ and the $h_{xy} \in \mathcal{A}$ as required.

**Added**

The next step in the proof is to use the $h_{xy}$ that were just constructed to show

$$\forall f \in C^0(X,\mathbb{R}) : \forall x \in X: \forall \varepsilon >0 : \exists g_x \in \overline{\mathcal{A}}: g_x(x) > f(x) \text{ and } g_x \le f+\varepsilon\text{,}$$ where  $g_x \le f+\varepsilon$ means that for all $p \in X$ we have $g_x(p) \le f(p) + \varepsilon$, so it lies uniformly below. To do this he defines an open cover based on the $h_{xy}$ (for the fixed $x$ we are trying to show this for) and varying $y \neq x$. The compactness then allows to make it into a "finite problem" where we can take the minimum of finitely many $h_{xy}$ to do the job of $g_x$, getting rid of the infinitely many $y \neq x$ that we were dealing with.

The very first part of the proof has shown the very useful fact:

$$h_1, h_2 \in \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \min(h_1, h_2),\max(h_1,h_2) \in \overline{\mathcal{A}}$$ which means that the $g_x$ all lie in $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ as required.

The final step is to use the $g_x$ and get rid of the $x$, essentially$$\forall f \forall \varepsilon \exists g \in \overline{\mathcal{A}}: f \le g \le f+\varepsilon\text{,}$$ again using compactness, open covers and a $\max$ or $\min$, and as we use members of $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ these lie in $\overline{\overline{\mathcal{A}}} = \overline{\mathcal{A}}$; in fact the first part of the proof can we seen as a lemma that the closure of an algebra is also an algebra, which is moreover closed under taking of $\min, \max$ and absolute values (so it has a lattice structure, besides the linear and multiplicative structure); I've sometimes seen the proof built up in that way, explicitly.

That last property is exactly what you want: $g$ lies in a small band defined by $\varepsilon$, because every inequality is now uniform over $x$. This is a common theme in compactness proofs: you can "do something" for every point in $X$ separately , and the compactness allows one to do this for all $x$ simultaneously, using some "finiteness argument". The last inequality implies that

$$||f -g||_{\infty} = \sup \{|f(x) - g(x)|:  x \in X\} \le \varepsilon\text{,}$$ or equivalently that $g \in B(f,2\varepsilon)$ where the open ball is taken wrt this metric is defined by the norm $||\cdot||_{\infty}$. So every ball around $f$ with any centre $r>0$ intersects $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$, as witnessed by $g$ (say, take $\varepsilon < \frac{r}{2}$), so 
$f \in \overline{\overline{\mathcal{A}}} = \overline{\mathcal{A}}$, and as $f$ is arbitrary $\overline{\mathcal{A}} = C^0(X,Y)$ which was the goal.

Note that in a metric space $(M,d)$ (that $C^0(X,Y)$ with the uniform norm metric is) a set $D\subseteq M$ is dense if its closure equals the whole space, which means that for every $x \in M$, $x$ should be in $\overline{D}$ which means that every open ball $B(x,r)$ around $x$ should intersect $D$. The above is just this fact applied to the particular case at hand.

Hopefully the structure / logic of the proof is more clear this way. The goal is to reach the final stage, where starting with some $f$ and $\varepsilon>0$ we need some $g$ from the algebra (or its closure) uniformly close to $f$. We cannot do it right away, so first we must find the $g_x$ that are close to $f$ at $x$ and that stay uniformly below $f+\varepsilon$, and from these we make the required $g$. But to make the $g_x$ we need the $h_{xy}$ to fix things "locally" (for $x$ and $y$) and use the compactness again.. It's often a good idea to read longer proofs backwards.
Assume we have the $g$ are we done? (yes), assuming we have the $g_x$ can we make a $g$ (yes), assuming we have $h_{xy}$ can we make $g_x$ (yes again) and to make these we need the assumptions on the algebra (it separates points and has constant functions) and we stay in the closure because that's what taking a min and max "costs" you. (You cannot prove that all algebras are closed under taking $\min$, but closed ones are).

Comment: I see :) and following the PDF of the other question, where it says "Second, we shall show that.." why do we want to show that, I mean I don't see the relation between the density of A and the "for all continuous functions and for all.."  Masacroso user answer something about it but it's still not clear.

Comment: @AaronMartinez I added explanations. Hopefully they help you understand the proof a bit better.

Comment: @AaronMartinez It seems you're quite struggling with it. Weierstrass proofs in this generality do assume familiarity (in a mild way) with quite a bit of topological arguments. It might be a bit too early for you if you didn't do any general topology, then the type of arguments would be "alien" to you in these cases. In my university we had a good grounding in "metric topology" first before doing advanced analysis. That was in our case a good idea, the analysis then serves as an application for a lot of the abstract metric space theory (which covered compactness, Lebesgue numbers etc.)

Comment: Oh so that's why It's really difficult to understand :( do you think that I should  look for another proof? you know what, I think I don't even know how to search in google, I mean I haven't notice this proof had topological arguments.Could you suggest me (or send me) a proof for my level ?

Comment: @AaronMartinez if you want to prove the theorem as stated, you cannot avoid it. The proof you have is actually quite understandable in my opinion. Although the start is "sketchy ", i.e. needs more detail, to be completely rigorous.

Comment: well now the proof is different, it's less difficult (because of you) but as you might know I have to explain it  to my professor, and you know, the less complicated the better :)